# Sticking a bar to the bottom of the screen

Tags: android

I have a scrollview that extends beyond the visible screen, but I would like to keep a bar affixed to the bottom of the screen. How do I do so while still allowing the user to scroll beyond the visible screen?

Answer (score 1):

you can make a LinearLayout vertical mode, put a scrollview first, then another layout that is your bar, it will be below the scrollview